# Preloading scripts and parsing `args` in the spark-shell

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a test script to read a text file provided as a parameter like below:

test.scala:

```
$ cat test.scala
import scala.io.Source

val filename = args(0)
for (line <- Source.fromFile(filename).getLines) {
    println(line)
}
```

I want to read a text file below:

```
$ cat test.txt
test1
test2
test3
```

I need to run the scala in commandline like below:

```
spark-shell -i test.scala test.txt
```

I expect test.txt is recognized as `args(0)`, but I see the output like:

> :26: error: not found: value args
>            val filename = args(0)

Can anyone enlighten me on what is the right usage to do this? Thank you very much.

UPDATE:

```
cat test.scala
import scala.io.Source

val args = spark.sqlContext.getConf("spark.driver.args").split(",")
val filename = args(0)

for (line <- Source.fromFile(filename).getLines) {
    println(line)
}
```

Test result:
 `spark-shell -i test.scala --conf spark.driver.args="test.txt"`

> ```
>  SQL context available as sqlContext. Loading test.scala... import
>  scala.io.Source <console>:26: error: not found: value spark
>           val args = spark.sqlContext.getConf("spark.driver.args").split(",")
> ```

Comment: both spark 1.6 and 2.3, thanks

Comment: [How to pass arguments/parameters to a SCALA script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50876988/10465355) might be worth checking.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29928999/passing-command-line-arguments-to-spark-shell

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your custom `--conf` argument value to spark. Here is the way how you can pass your arguments:

```
import scala.io.Source

val args = spark.sqlContext.getConf("spark.driver.args").split(",")
val arg1 = args(0)
val arg2 = arg(1)
print(arg1)
```

In `--conf`, I've to pass value of `spark.driver.args` arguments. So the final command to run the script will be :

```
spark-shell -i test.scala --conf spark.driver.args="param1value,param2value,param3value"
```

Comment: Thank you very much. would this work for spark 1.6? UPDATE made to the question.

Comment: It works for spark 2.3.  `SparkSession` has been introduced from `spark-2.0`, So you'll get `spark not found` error if you use less than spark version 2.0. So first initialize `SqlContext` obj and it should work then. I would suggest to update your spark env to get more features and better performance.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
import scala.io.Source

val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)

val args = sqlContext.getConf("spark.driver.args").split(",")

println(args)

args
```